# E: Package 'nautilus-wipe' has no installation candidate Ubuntu MATE 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt, mate

I tried to install `nautilus-wipe` on MATE 22.10 which cannot find the package:

```
$ sudo apt install nautilus-wipe
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package nautilus-wipe is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nautilus-wipe' has no installation candidate
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:    22.10
Codename:   kinetic
```

Sources:

- http://wipetools.tuxfamily.org/nautilus-wipe.html
- https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-wipe/tree

Packages:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nautilus-wipe&searchon=names

  - Package nautilus-wipe

    - bionic (18.04LTS) (utils): Secure deletion extension for Nautilus [universe]
      0.3-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    - focal (20.04LTS) (utils): Secure deletion extension for Nautilus [universe]
      0.3-2: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x
    - jammy (22.04LTS) (utils): Secure deletion extension for Nautilus [universe]
      0.3.1-2: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x

Any suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: Try [ubuntu.se]. This doesn't look like a programming question so isn't really suitable here