# No package libnautilus-extension to build ubuntu-wipe from source Ubuntu MATE 22.10

Tags: nautilus, mate

As the [nautilus-wipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75636085/e-package-nautilus-wipe-has-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-mate-22-10) tool cannot be installed on MATE 22.10, I tried to configure/build from [source](http://download.tuxfamily.org/wipetools/releases/nautilus-wipe/) script on MATE 22.10 results in the following error:

`No package 'libnautilus-extension' found`

Configure log:

```bash
nautilus-wipe-0.3.1$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9... yes
checking for itstool... itstool
checking for xmllint... xmllint
checking for GTK package to use... gtk+-2.0
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for GTK... yes
checking for LIBNAUTILUS_EXTENSION... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libnautilus-extension >= 2.0) were not met:

No package 'libnautilus-extension' found
```

All `libnautilus-extension` installed:

```
$ apt search nautilus-extension
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libnautilus-extension-dev/kinetic-updates,kinetic-security,now 1:43.0-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
  libraries for nautilus components - development version

libnautilus-extension4/kinetic-updates,kinetic-security,now 1:43.0-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
  libraries for nautilus components - runtime version

nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal/kinetic,now 3.46.2-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
  GNOME terminal emulator application - Nautilus extension
```

What is the procedure to configure/build `nautilus-wipe` to fix `No package 'libnautilus-extension' found` on MATE 22.10?